# Mixed Model logistic regression with lots of zero's

Tags: binary-data, glmm

Imagine a cluster randomized trial with a binary outcome. Now let's say that the clusters aren't too large (e.g. 10 observations per cluster) and that in the control arm, the event is not so abundant (e.g. 10% - event is a positive thing).

The natural approach of analyzing the resulting data - as I see it - would be a mixed model logistic regression. However, I notice in simulation that if there is a substantial amount of clusters with zero events, then the glmm warns for a singular fit (but still delivering estimates). These singular fits blow up the type I error when I simulate under H0 (when I discard the singular fits, simulated power and type I error is as expected).

Info on the simulation:

- Assume $p_0$ and $p_1$ the proportions of positive outcomes in both arms
- Starting from an ICC of 0.05, calculate a between-cluster variance for $p_{0i}$ and $p_{1j}$
- Choose a number of clusters and a number of within-cluster measurements
- Draw $p_{0/1i}$ for each cluster (0 or 1 depending on treatment-assignment)
- Simulate outcomes based on these $p_{0/1i}$ 's
- Analyze with mixed model logistic regression and see there are a lot of convergence issues when chosing $p_0$ rather small, probably because there are too many clusters with zero positive outcomes, which doesn't work very well with the log-link. The problem is that these cases clearly blow up the type I error. Filtering them out, produces the expected power/type I error (dependent on the chosen $p_0$ and $p_1$) - leaving them in, increases the proportion of significant results.

So my question: which alternatives for GLMM to consider to analyse a cluster randomized trial when a decent amount of clusters is expected to contain zeros?

Comment: How do you simulate? Following the assumptions of a mixed logistic model?

Comment: @FlorianHartig Info added, hope it is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your point 2, I'm still not sure if that is exactly the assumption of a logistic GLMM, where you would expect a normal distribution of between-cluster heterogeneity on the scale of the linear predictor.

Anyway, assuming that what you describe in your simulation is the data-generating process of a logistic GLMM, I would say there is nothing to improve about the likelihood (i.e. no sense in switching the model). It's simply a problem of the numerical estimation procedure, i.e. that the optimiser gets are problem if the likelihood is very flat for the zero groups. If you are not interested in the cluster estimates, but only in the population estimate (mean slope for all clusters), there may be little consequences of this (you can check this, looking at coverage / type I error rates of the estimate for the population estimate). If you want to fully represent the uncertainty of the zero clusters in the population estimate, you would probably have to go Bayesian. You can fit a logistic GLMM conveniently using brms. It may help to add some mild regularisation on all parameter priors.

Another option would be of course to change the data collection, i.e. increase the number of subjects per clusters, so that the problem disappears.